# Unity3D: How do I ignore a collision without disabling future collisions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a 2D flocking object that uses a nested trigger collider to establish separation and a normal collider to handle collisions with other objects. (The collider is set to ignore everything in the same layer.)

I don't really like this setup, and would rather fold the avoidance code into the parent object's OnCollisionEnter2D method. Physics2D.IgnoreCollision does what it says on the box, but then all subsequent collisions are ignored.

Is there a way to make two colliders transparent to one another without having them completely ignore one another? Alternatively, is there a way to activate normal collision behaviour from OnTriggerEnter2D?

Or am I being an idiot (as usual) and missing an obvious solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set that specific collider as trigger.

In example - have a gameobject on a layer that collides with all layers except the one that you want to be 'transparent' and then have another gameobject that only collides with objects on the same layer but set it's collider to trigger.

Would that work for you?

Comment: Aye, this is what I'm doing already. I was hoping to consolidate as much code as possible into a single collision call for performance reasons. Oh well.

Comment: I don't really see any other performance-friendly way to do that.

Comment: Yes, I do believe you're right. I think I was overthinking it. Thanks for your input!